# Would you use Assertion or Dynamic Acl?

Tags: php, authorization, service-layer, zend-acl, assertion

I'm implementing an `AuthorizationService`, basically it extends `Zend_Acl` and override `authenticate()` method to work with my own adapter.

Let's say I've `User`, `Article`, `ArticleComment`, `ArticleVote`, `CommentVote`.

My rules are simple:

- An Member can edit its own Article
- An Member can cast a vote on any Article
- A Guest can't cast a vote on Comment
- A Guest can't cast more than 10 votes per day.

However, I'm not sure on how to implement this, for the last rules, it's easy, it should be an Assertion, however, what about the Member who can edit their own Article?

Should I create a dynamic Acl, and create a resource like 'Article-545' and a Role 'User-5656' and then create an Acl rules, or have a more generic 'Article' resource, and a generic role 'User', and use an Assertion to authorize User 545 to edit Article 5656?

How do you do, any advices?

Comment: Did you ever come to any conclusions on this question? I'd be keen to see them if so.